# HTML<video> webcam access not working in Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari, webcam

I am trying to display my Macbook's camera on a website. It works in Firefox, but not in Safari or Chrome. http://idolmemory.com/camera_test.html

Note: I have another site that displays the camera, and it works just fine in Chrome. https://www.ibiz.cards/

1) Is there something that could be blocking the camera for the first domain?
2) Why doesn't the webcam ever work on Safari?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<video autoplay="true" id="thevideo"></video>

<script>
var video = document.querySelector("#thevideo");

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
}

function handleVideo(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}

function videoError(e) {
    alert("error loading camera");
}
</script>
```

Edit: So Chrome wasn't working because to display the webcam, the site must have SSL. But I still would like any answers about Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Navigator.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) is deprecated as per the API warning below:

> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some
>   browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped.
>   Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may
>   break at any time.

[image: Browser Support]

**Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia

As you can see above, Safari does not support this at all, nor does IE. You should use the newer [MediaDevices.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) instead. However, this is also not supported by them yet either.